# Who has seen your profile

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I would like to ask you how could I solve this problem. I would like to make this feature to my site. But I do not know exactly what would be the best solution. I was thinking of mysql table: something like this

```
ID | id_user_who | user_seen
 1       2             10
```

User with id 2 seen user with id 10. But is it good solution?

Comment: I think it's the only solution, but SO isn't he place for asking this question.

Comment: Well, does this solution work for you?  Think of it in terms of how you're connecting your entities.  You have a Person entity and another Person entity, and you need to connect them.  One Person can see many other Persons, and many Persons can be seen by one Person.  Since it's a many-to-many relationship, it probably needs a connecting table like this one.

Comment: "is it a good solution" is not a good question to ask here. someone's 'good' is another's 'bad' and a third's "holy crap that's horrible".

Comment: Ofc, I would have another table with users and their IDs

Comment: My only suggestion would be to use better names.  `id_user_who` isn't very descriptive of what it represents, and both of the FK fields have different conventions of whether or not they specify that it's an `id`.

Comment: Why wouldn't be this a good question for SO? He is asking what is the most efficient way to implement this type of feature and he is showing what he has implemented so far. It is a good programming question.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good solution, and, I believe, the only right approach. Just get rid of the `ID` column (the first column), this is a most certainly useless [surrogate key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key). Instead, set the pair `(id_user_who, user_seen)` as the primary key.

Please note that a primary key *is* and index, you wouldn't need any additional index.

As advised by David, name your columns more carefully, you will thank yourself for doing so in a few months from now, when you try to figure out what the hell these columns mean.

I would rather suggest something like `visitor_id` and `visited_id`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it's really a question for SO....
BUT in any case if I do something like that I would add a timestamp, or a number of hits (& last visit)...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is a good solution. Make sure your columns are indexed so lookups/counts are fast.  You may also want to consider adding a "date_viewed" column so you can expire records if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

That seems like an alright solution. It makes sense to use. I agree with @J.D. Make sure it's indexed, and possibly add a date_viewed column. That way you have more options when sorting through the data.